# Running a tester file in the VSC terminal - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have made a tester file to check my other files are implementing correctly, however I can only get an output by clicking run on the file  (top right green arrow). When I type 'python Test.py' in the terminal I get :

> Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site'
>
> Current thread 0x0000000102c0ce00 (most recent call first):

I assume this is an environment issue for my terminal? I am in the correct folder (one above Test.py).

Any ideas how I can change this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more of you file structure? Since you are in a folder above Test.py, running python Test.py would only look in that folder and others in your path variable, unless you are using modules and `__init__.py` files. You should be able to use `python Folder/Test.py`, or create modules. Running with the top right green arrow will run the current file, so it knows where the file is located, as opposed to the terminal where you are one folder above.

Comment: I have 'Folder' with 'test.py' inside that folder (and other files). In the terminal did 'cd *file_path_to_Folder*', so think I should be in the right place to run 'python Test.py'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the python interpreter you are taking when you run `python Test.py` in the terminal is different from the one when you click the `Run Python File in Terminal`(green triangle) button.

Could you type this command in the VSCode terminal(**CMD: where python; Powershell: get-command python**) to check which python you are using when you take `python Test.py` command to run your python file? And compare it with another one.